# Can President Trump force a coalition if he loses the election?

Tags: united-states, president, presidential-election, contested-election

When Trump was facing impeachment there were threats from some of his supporters that they would plunge the country into a civil war. Supposing the election is close, what if he refuses to leave the White House after losing the upcoming election and his supporters take up arms to keep him in office, would the US government and new president cave into his demands by forming a coalition?

Comment: This is not really a meaningful concept in the US system. Are you asking whether the Constitution would be replaced with a parliamentary system that would enable this?

Comment: Well, he's no longer the President so he has no authority and can be removed. Doubt this would even be something plausible.

Comment: A coalition with who, exactly?

Comment: Problem with this question is it asks *would the US government and new president cave into his demands by forming a coalition*, which is effectively asking for a prediction of the future. How would anyone be able to do that? Nobody can say for certain who is going to win the election, let alone what the winner is going to do.

Comment: re: "refuses to leave the White House"? We elect presidents. Power is not apportioned to whomever happens to occupy a building like a game of king of the castle; it is entrusted to the winner of the EC.

Comment: I'm pretty sure in the US, such thing cannot be done. It's a system that thinks these kinds of situation and when the time of a president to leave office, they'll leave the easy way or the hard way.

Comment: Trumps term ends on 2021-01-21T12:01 EST, when a new president is sworn in.

Comment: Of course this can be done.  If the army remains loyal to him, he can suspend the constitution, declare the elections invalid, and throne himself dictator.  Probably the army will however choose the constitution over Trump.

Comment: @gerrit But that wouldn't be a coalition, it would be a coup.

Comment: @divibisan Nobody can perform a coup alone, a coup is performed by a coalition of conspirators.  I can completely imagine a group taking power (or trying to) in a coup calling itself the *National Coalition for Restoration of Law and Order* or something similar.

Comment: Would this be acceptable if it was reworded to ask if there is a constitutional mechanism that would allow a president to form a coalition?

Comment: @MartinSchröder you're off by a day and a minute.  The term ends at 2021-01-20T12:00 EST.  Furthermore, the term ends even if a new president isn't sworn in.

Comment: Citation for the assertion "his supporters would plunge the US into civil war. Down voted and voted for deletion,

Comment: As a practical matter, the number of Trump supporters (using support in the loosest sense) is already a distinct minority of the population: https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/trump-approval-ratings/  One would suppose that only a fraction of those would support him to the extent of abandoning the Constitution.  That fraction is fairly well dispersed around the country, so any civil war would be a non-starter.  Riots, maybe, but I suspect it would be more likely that people would take up arms to force him out, if he tried to hang on to the office.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Note: I originally considered voting to close the question as too hypothetical, but technically I think it has a logical answer.*

This scenario describes a [coup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coup_d%27%C3%A9tat): taking power by force or threat. The success of a coup usually depends whether the army supports it or not. If the coup succeeds the dictator has no reason to form a coalition with anybody. If the coup fails, the wannabe dictator and their accomplices are judged for treason, not invited to form a coalition.

[edit] As suggested in the comments, in this case the Secret Service would probably just remove the non-elected president from the White House (unless they decide to support the coup, which is very unlikely). Presumably the illegal attempt to seize power would still be punishable.

Comment: For the particular case in the question, the secret service may be important. The outgoing president would presumably no longer be authorized to be in the White House, so the secret service should remove him.

Comment: this would be more of a reverse coup, not taking power but keeping it.

Comment: @dandavis It would be a coup.  It would overthrow the legal order, the constitution, the courts, etc.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Since we are being hypothetical anyway: who appoints members of the secret service, who appoints top generals?  Could the President replace them all with people who they believe will remain loyal to them in the event of the scenario considered in the question?

Comment: The Secret Service is singular.